# TypeError: Calculator.main() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python

```
import math


class Calculator():
    def __init__(self, num1=0.0, op=None, num2=0.0, result=None):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.op = op
        self.num2 = num2
        self.result = result

    def main(self, num1, op, num2, result):
        if op == "+":
            result = float(num1) + float(num2)
            print(result)
        elif op == "-":
            result = float(num1) - float(num2)
            print(result)
        elif op == "*":
            result = float(num1) * float(num2)
            print(result)
        elif op == "/" and float(num2) == 0:
            result = None
            print("You can't divide by zero")
            p.main(self, num1, op, num2, result)
        elif op == "/" and float(num2) != 0:
            result = float(num1) / float(num2)
            print(result)
        elif op == "power":
            result = float(num1)**float(num2)
            print(result)
        else:
            print("invalid input")


while True:
    p = Calculator()
    p.main(num1=input("Write a number: "),
           op=input("+ or - or * or / or power: "),
           num2=input("Write another number: "),
           result=None)
    ans = input("Would you like to do another equation: ")
    if ans == "yes":
        p.main()
        ans = input("Would you like to do another equation: ")
    elif ans == "no":
        exit()
```

I tried dividing 5 by 6 to test out if everything was working fine and I got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\HelloWorld python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 37, in 
p.main(num1=input("Write a number: "),
File "d:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\HelloWorld python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 24, in main
p.main(self, num1, op, num2, result)
TypeError: Calculator.main() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Comment: This program works for me with no exceptions in python 3.8.  I ran a few inputs and got good looking answers printed to the console.

Comment: Not related to the error, but why is `result` a parameter of the function?

Comment: It's because OP is still at the messing-around stage where they're figuring out how functions/OOP work.  I'm sure they'll get there.  :P

Comment: @Samwise I agree. My comment was just a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
            p.main(self, num1, op, num2, result)
```

should be:

```
            self.main(num1, op, num2, result)
```

This will raise a different error, however, which is that by calling the same function with the same parameters you get the same result, which is another call to the same function (this then repeats about a thousand times, until a recursion error is raised).  What needs to happen instead is that you need to prompt the user for new inputs; the function that handles the error should be the function that takes the input from the user.

One way to make this easy is using exceptions, which actually happens automatically if you just do the division by zero and let it raise a `ZeroDivisionError`.  Just have the code that takes the input catch that exception so it can re-prompt the user:

```
class Calculator():
    def operate(self, num1: float, op: str, num2: float) -> float:
        """Perform one operation according to the value of op.
        May raise ValueError or ZeroDivisionError."""
        if op == "+":
            return num1 + num2
        elif op == "-":
            return num1 - num2
        elif op == "*":
            return num1 * num2
        elif op == "/":
            return num1 / num2
        elif op == "power":
            return num1 ** num2
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"invalid operator {op}")

    def do_one_equation(self) -> None:
        """Prompt the user for input and do one equation.
        Loop on invalid input until we have one successful result."""
        while True:
            try:
                result = self.operate(
                    float(input("Write a number: ")),
                    input("+ or - or * or / or power: "),
                    float(input("Write another number: "))
                )
                print(result)
                return
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("You can't divide by zero")
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid input")


p = Calculator()
while True:
    p.do_one_equation()
    if input("Would you like to do another equation: ") == "no":
        break
```

Note in the code above that `result` becomes whatever is `return`ed by the `operate()` method.  The arguments to the function are its *input*, and the result should be its *output* (i.e. the thing you `return`).

Comment: Yes, that line causes the error, but this line makes no sense anyway.

Comment: @eljokoir That's why I said "this line makes no sense anyway". And you should follow the link to the answer Samwise gave.